# In PHPstorm , is any way to avoid save all open documents instead current active document?

Tags: save, phpstorm

I use PHPstorm 2017.2.4 for php programming.One of the bad features of the phpstorm software is that there is no button to save changes to just one file instead of saving all files.

In PHPstorm 2017 2.4 , is any way to prevent save change in all open documents  and just save change of one open document that is modified?

I googled and search in stackoverflow but I couldn't find my answer.

Comment: Please consider reforming the sentences, they are somehow not understandable for me.

Comment: *"One of the bad features of the PhpStorm software is that there is no button to save changes to just one file instead of saving all files."* It's very personal opinion. I for example love that. Took few weeks to get used to it but then it became absolutely natural. At the same time -- in another IDE (e.g. Delphi, that I use pretty rarely these days) I would not like to have that feature -- but that's mainly for the forms; for code it's OK.

Comment: @dena If you need -- create new question but DO NOT replace original answered question with new content.

Comment: Sorry I did not know